# C# RSA decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, key, rsa

I have writed this code for decrypt a byte array with the RSA algorithm:

the RSA Key class:

```
    public class RsaKeys
    {
        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// The modulus N.
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] N
        { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The public exponent E.
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] E
        { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The private exponent E.
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] D
        { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

the code for the decryption:

```
    public static byte[] RsaDecryptByteToByte(byte[] Byte, RsaKeys Key) // TODO: test me
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider myRsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

        RSAParameters rsaParams = new RSAParameters();

        rsaParams.D = Key.D;
        rsaParams.Exponent = Key.E;
        rsaParams.Modulus = Key.N;

        myRsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);

        return myRsa.Decrypt(Byte, false); // ERROR!!!
    }
```

but in the last line (myRsa.Decrypt(Byte, false);) comes out an error ( "Key does not exist.") :(

Comment: how do you setup the byte arrays (the ones you send to your method) in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about all the other fields of the RSAParameters object? There are many more fields for a private key that you are not providing.

Comment: It is true that, mathematically, only (N,D) are needed. However, some implementations require the full PKCS#1 suite of private key parameters. I don't know if Microsoft's is one of those but you can do a simple experiment to find out.

Comment: you are right, sorry :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm

Answer (score -3):

change your param "Key" => "key" (lowercase)

Comment: Case has nothing to do with it here; the names he gives parameters does not affect logic.